# Is there any sign or way to use in select(query) sqlite3 python that return all dat in a column?

Tags: python, sqlite, select, where-clause

I try to execute this sqlite3 query in Python. I need a query that sometimes search  a Integer from database and sometimes when a client input nothing return all data column. I use two way of var select but all of them return null from database

```
codeNumber = input ("please insert that code number you need")
codeNumber = [] ( # sometimes is integer (4580) sometimes client input nothing)
firstType = "1"
secondType = "5"



res2 = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM CS1 WHERE firstType=? AND secondType=? AND codeNumber = ?  
order by rowid ", (firstType, secondType, codeNumber))


for row in res2:
    print(row)

print('done !!! ')
```

When the client input nothing return NULL from database but I need return all of data in column
Is there any sign to use in select(query) sqlite3 python that return all dat in a column like * (codeNumber = *) or how can I solve this problem to search a column with this condition

Comment: if you want all codeNumbers simply remove your AND codeNumber = ? part

Comment: What means "return error"? If there are error messages show the full traceback(s) of the error(s) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I know this, I describe that when client input nothing I want to return all of codeNumber column and when client input  a integer search that integer @Noah

Comment: when I put nothing for codeNumber return from database nothing, not a error I edited the question @MichaelButscher

Comment: It needs a simple if-block to check if thr input is the empty string and, depending on the check, require the particular code number in the query or execute the reduced query that Noah proposed.